# How to start openstack-services?

Tags: openstack

I installed rdo-openstack-packstack-allinone on Fedora21, how to start openstack- services after rebooting,i am a new bird in openstack.
Thank you warm-hearted!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To run all the openstack services

```
openstack-service start
```

to stop all services

```
openstack-service stop
```

to check status:

```
openstack-service status
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This needs few packages to be installed like openstack-utils and dnsmasq-utils

Answer (score 2):

Generally these services get started on reboot. If not run following in terminal to start all openstack services.

```
for i in /etc/init.d/openstack-*; do $i start; done
for i in /etc/init.d/neutron-*; do $i start; done
```

Answer (score 1):

On Fedora 21 you have SystemD, you can use systemctl command.
I usually run the command

```
$ for SERVICE in `systemctl -a | grep -e openstack- -e neutron -e httpd | awk '{ print$1 }'`; do systemctl restart $SERVICE; done
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the step to stop multiple service in one single shot. If you have to work with many services (10, 50, 100, etc. services) and you want to stop all of them to perform maintenance on a Server and then start all of them, it is easier to create a bat file. You are going to do it once and you can use it anytime you want.

1. Open a text editor like notepad(NOT word or wordpad)
2. Type or copy this text: @ECHO OFF. ECHO. ECHO This is a batch file. ECHO. PAUSE. CLS. EXIT.
3. Save this as batchfile.bat, make sure there is no .txt extension after the .bat.
4. Double-click the file icon.

Here is an example XY company services, I put them in one TXT file and follow the above steps and save it as stopservices.bat

```
cls
REM *******************************************
REM **stop all XY company Services           **
REM *******************************************

net stop XYPQATS_3
net stop XYUSLVBULK
net stop XYMILLTS
net stop XYMILLBULK
net stop XYHANDTS
net stop XYHANDBULK
net stop XYSAPRTS
net stop XYSAPRBULK
net stop XYTOMMTS
net stop XYTOMMBULK
net stop XYTGTETS
net stop XYTGTEBULK
net stop XYSPANTS
net stop XYSPANBULK
net stop XYLTAPTS
net stop XYLTAPBULK
```

After that I just have to click on the new bat file and this stop all the services one by one for me.

If you want more details how to create a bat file here is a link that provide you stop by step. Note if you want start them in one you just have to right click your bat file and press Ctrl+H and replace stop with start and save the file with the new name stopservice.bat

http://www.wikihow.com/Write-a-Batch-File

Answer (score 0):

For openstack setup on centos, we can try the following command to start all openstack service:

```
[root@controller1 home]# for s in `systemctl list-unit-files | grep openstack| awk '{print $1}'`; do systemctl start $s; done
```